# What is the term for content that is only shown to new users?

Tags: onboarding

What is the commonly accepted term for the content that is shown to users after they sign up? Things like welcome panels, "did you know", etc.. Content that can be closed (i.e. don't show me this again).

I'm *not* talking about guided tours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On-boarding content/widget. On-boarding implies process that takes after hiring/signup/registration.

Then you can get more descriptive.

On-boarding Tutorial
On-boarding Promo